# The emulator process for AVD was terminated 1073741515 (0xc0000135). MFPlat.DLL was not found

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sdk, emulation

My Emulator just stopped opening after Android Studio update or after some development kit installations just showing "The emulator process for AVD was terminated". It was working fine before update.

It is not memory problem because I have a lot of free space.

I took Error code from idea.log (C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2020.3\log\idea.log)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically what I had to do is install "Additional Windows Features", which is weird because I'm having Windows 10 Pro N version.

To install you go through Settings -> Apps -> Apps & features tab -> Optional features -> Add a feature -> Media Feature Pack.

Search for it and after installation it will work fine :)

Answer (score 0):

I have Windows 10 N 22H2 and this is in a slightly different location for me (than described in the existing answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/76037491/7733418):
Settings -> System -> Optional features -> Add a feature -> search for Media Feature Pack and install.