# The emulator process for AVD has terminated - Emulator terminated with exit code -1073741701

Tags: android, emulation, qemu

I installed Android Studio Girafe on my "Windows 10 Enterprise N LTSC" and I cannot launch the emulator.

Error : The emulator process for AVD XXX has terminated.

In idea.log:

```
2023-11-05 17:31:18,249 [1218299] SEVERE - Emulator: Pixel_3a_API_34_extension_level_7_x86_64 - Emulator terminated with exit code -1073741515
java.lang.Throwable: Emulator terminated with exit code -1073741515
      at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:202)
      at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorProcessHandler$ConsoleListener.onTextAvailable(EmulatorProcessHandler.kt:89)
      at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor64.invoke(Unknown Source)
      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
      at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler$2.invoke(ProcessHandler.java:248)
      at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy44.onTextAvailable(Unknown Source)
```

I tried to launch with command console :

```
2023-11-05 17:31:18,218 [1218268]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel_3a_API_34_extension_level_7_x86_64 - C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Pixel_3a_API_34_extension_level_7_x86_64 -qt-hide-window -grpc-use-token -idle-grpc-timeout 3002023-11-05 17:31:18,233 [1218283]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel_3a_API_34_extension_level_7_x86_64 - Android emulator version 32.1.15.0 (build_id 10696886) (CL:N/A)2023-11-05 17:31:18,233 [1218283]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel_3a_API_34_extension_level_7_x86_64 - Found systemPath C:\Users\ John\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-34\google_apis\x86_64\
```

I have an error popup with "MFPlat.dll is not found..."

I tried what is recommended on this link : [The emulator process for AVD was terminated 1073741515 (0xc0000135). MFPlat.DLL was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76037490/the-emulator-process-for-avd-was-terminated-1073741515-0xc0000135-mfplat-dll)

And I copy-paste the mfplat.dll (c:/Windows/sysWOW64/ because is an 64Bit OS) in the emulator folder at C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator.

I have now a new error : Process finished with exit code -1073741701 (0xC000007B)

I have 16GB of RAM, 130GB of free space on my computer and intel core I5 10th generation and Android Emulator 32.1.15.

Thks for your help.

Sébastien